# what is the keyboard shortcut as 'option + double-click' in xcode?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

'Find Text in Documentation of a symbol' shortcut is 'option + double-click' in xcode.

but this is simultaneously using keyboard and mouse .

I want to know 'Find Text in Documentation of a symbol' shortcut only in keyboard not using mouse.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut to find text in xcode

```
Find in Workspace…                 ⇧⌘F  Shift-Command-F

Find and Replace in Workspace…     ⌥⇧⌘F Option-Shift-Command-F

Find…                              ⌘F   Command-F

Find and Replace…                  ⌥⌘F  Option-Command-F
```

other shortcuts can be found here. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/MenuCommands/MenuCommands014.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010560-CH2-SW1

Comment: thanks. but my question is 'Find Text in Documentation of a symbol' key shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding shortcut only in keyboard not using mouse is a little not easy to use:

```
Search Documentation for Selected Text         ⌃⌥⌘/         Control-Option-Command-/
```

Another easier to use shortcut is `Command-Click`.

Comment: thanks. but 'option + double-click' and ⌃⌥⌘/ are different result.

Comment: @user2077767 Yes, they are a little different. I can't find better ones, sorry. I think Command-Click is very good if you accept mouse click.